# PHP PDO execute() returning duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For this code:

```
$title = '0';
$subTitle = '1';
$tableName = 'someString';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `".$title."`, `".$subTitle."` FROM `".$tableName."_data` WHERE `id` = :key");

$stmt->bindValue(':key', '127');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

I get $result as this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 91651
            [1] => 91651 - DESCRIPTION
            [2] => 91651 - DESCRIPTION
        )

)
```

When the expected result should be this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 91651
            [1] => 91651 - DESCRIPTION
        )

)
```

When I run the same query in mySQL, it returns the expected result. When it is executed via PHP PDO, it adds a duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds silly, but are you completely certain you don't have duplicate keys? And have you tried using the DISTINCT keyword, to mask out any irregularities like that?

Comment: Yes, how @ChrisCooney said. There is only 1 way to prevend happening this. Write in your code something like ... "select with this id, rememember it and if other row is with same id, then continue; "

Comment: Actually, the primary issue was me being bad at database structure. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by checking with someone better at databases than myself...

I foolishly named the columns as integer values.

So, what appeared as "duplicate values" was just the fact that the column number and the column name were the same!

In conclusion, I am bad at database structure.

Answer (score 5):

Use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of `fetchAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the fetch_style and fetch_argument and set it to a value you need.

see sample #3:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

sometimes dep. on your php version/pdo version there is a bug when using bindvalue.
try to avoid that and use sample #3 instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could change to using fetch() instead of fetchAll(), that will return one row. But I'd just ensure in the database that id is unique.